# Short nerdy sci-fi story where scientists discover that the Earth is falling into a black hole

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, hard-sci-fi, black-hole

I remember finding a PDF of this on the internet a few years ago, so it may not be a published work. It is about a scientist who observes unnatural behavior in the sky, and after some analysis discovers that she(?) is observing a black hole close to Earth. She discusses these effects with other scientists with access to other telescope across the world. Near the end of the story, they find that due to relativistic effects, the planet is likely already *inside* the black hole, but they have yet to observe the light effects of this. It involves a section where the protagonists struggle to alert and convince the media. The author definitely does not shy away from gory scientific details and assumes the reader has at least an undergraduate understanding of astrophysics.

Apologies for the lack of more details. I remember not quite grasping all the physics but enjoying the overall plot. If anything comes to mind I'll update this post.